# Three conversions in C++ implicit conversion sequence

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

The page at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast states that up to three conversion sequences can be done in an implicit conversion sequence:

> Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>
> 1. zero or one standard conversion sequence
> 2. zero or one user-defined conversion
> 3. zero or one standard conversion sequence

What is an example of all three occurring?

Comment: Err, doesn't that page already provide a number of examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how all three could occur in a row. This would mean that you enable an implicit conversion between two language-defined types (let's say `int*` and `char`) with the intermediate of an user-defined class (call it `Stuff`). In my opinion, there is no reason for which you would want to do `int*`>`Stuff`>`char` (for example).

In other words, an implicit conversion from `A` to `B` means "`A` can be understood as being `B`". It sounds weird to add such a rule for language-defined type, and even weirder to explain it by "`A` can be understood as my class `C`" and "my class `C` can be understood as being `B`".

---

But for the rule to make sense, it is enough to provide an example of 1. and 2., and an example of 2. and 3. This is easy to do.

If you haven't figured it out, just consider a class (let's say `Date`) that can be converted to an `int` (user defined `Date::int()`) and that can be created from an `int` (copy constructor). Then, by considering the conversion `int`>`long` and `short` to `int` you have your examples.

```
Date d;
short a = 1234;
d = a; // Convertion short>int and int>Date (1. and 2.)
long b = d; // Convertion Date>int and int>long (2. and 3.)
```

Comment: now if d is a non-const lvalue and Date::operator int is a const member function, or if d has some other type derived from Date, you have all three

Comment: @Cubbi Meh, the conversion sequence for a non-const object binding to const reference of the same type is the identity conversion (i.e., none - see [over.ics.ref]/p1), and conversion functions are considered to be members of the class of the implied object argument for the purpose of defining the type of the implicit object parameter (see [over.match.funcs]/p4), so the implicit object parameter's type always matches the argument's.

Comment: @T.C. well, derived-to-base is ranked differently by over.ics.ref, Rank is a secondary property anyway.

Comment: @Cubbi It's not a derived-to-base, though. Per [over.match.funcs]/p4, the type of implicit object parameter for a conversion function is determined from its implied object argument, so even if `operator int` is in a base class, the type of its implicit object parameter is still `Derived&` (or `const Derived&`, etc.) with a `Derived` object.

Comment: @T.C. fine, but still, given the definition in [over.ics.user] "the initial standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the implicit object parameter of the conversion function.", even if it's a reference binding, it's "the initial standard conversion sequence"

Comment: @Cubbi Sure, but it's the identity (i.e., no) conversion. And if, for the purposes of this question, we count doing no conversion as a "standard conversion sequence", then the OP's question is trivially answered and there's not much point to it. (Incidentally, I'm not a big fan of cppreference's "zero or one" wording, which only makes sense if the identity conversion counts as the "zero".)

Comment: Most of the comments are over my head a bit, but I think the main conclusion is that all three at once aren't possible. I had the same thought as this would mean going from standard => user => standard, in which case I'd think just a standard => standard conversion would be applied. However I thought I may be misinterpreting so sought to clarify on SO. I'll choose as 'answered' if no further discussion over the next couple of days.