# Can someone give examples of a user-defined conversion sandwiched between two standard conversion sequences in C++?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

The C++ spec, allows:

> Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>
> zero or **one** standard conversion sequence;
> zero or **one** user-defined conversion;
> zero or **one** standard conversion sequence (only if a user-defined conversion is used).

from: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Order_of_the_conversions

It is easy and very common to see two such conversions:
(1) standard then user-defined OR (2) user-defined then standard

Can anyone provide resanable examples of:
standard conversion then user-defined conversion then another standard conversion.

The flowing is claiming that no such sequence is possible:
[Three conversions in C++ implicit conversion sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736336/three-conversions-in-c-implicit-conversion-sequence)

Meaning that the cppreferance page is wrong. Which one is right?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: [Three conversions in C++ implicit conversion sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736336/three-conversions-in-c-implicit-conversion-sequence)

Comment: The question should have been closed as duplicate of the above. The reason given now doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jason, Does this means that three such conversions are not possible? meaning the cpprefernce page is wrong? This is what the answer you are referring to is claiming.
Thanks!

Comment: Another duplicate: [C++ implicit conversions: Order of the conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433399/c-implicit-conversions-order-of-the-conversions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @dwto Yes, all three like `standard->user-defined->standard` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @dwto The page says "_zero or one_" and doesn't claim that there exists an implicit conversion sequence for every combination of these choices.

Comment: Thanks. The page is ambiguous, so I edited it, based on your answers.

Comment: @user17732522 It seems the cppreference people simplified the explanation too much. The language used for this explanation can be improved.

Comment: The edit is also wrong. A standard conversion sequence can be empty, i.e. be the identity conversion sequence. That would still be "one" standard conversion sequence. I simply assumed that this is not what you are interested in in your question. In fact the standard says that both standard conversion sequences exist unconditionally on a user-defined conversion sequence (https://eel.is/c++draft/over#ics.user-1.sentence-1).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/nxc6v4vTs) is my take:

```
struct X {
    operator int() const { return 1; }
};

struct Y: X {};

int main() {
    Y y;
    if (y) {}
}
```

- `Y` to `X` is a derived to base conversion, not user defined.
- `X` to `int` is user defined
- `int` to `bool` is not user defined

Comment: There's no conversion from `Y` to `X`, `operator int` is just called with the `X` subobject.

Comment: @PasserBy I was wondering the same. But isn't effectively the `this` pointer of the `Y` object converted to a pointer to type `X`?

Comment: I am also not sure the first is a standard conversion. I would think Y has inherited the member function and so it is a member function of Y.

Comment: Since within `X::operator int` the `this` pointer is always of type `X const*` and we start with a pointer of type `Y*`, I would say a conversion is happening. But then again to most hardware an `X const*` and a `Y*` are completely the same thing, I guess we'll have to ask a language lawyer if this qualifies as a conversion

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over#match.funcs.general-4.sentence-3

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you, but I'm still confused. As I understand it your link says, that for the purposes of overload resolution, `X::operator int` is considered to be a member of `Y` with an implicit object parameter of type `Y`. But then to invoke the conversion function, doesn't the `Y*` to `X*` conversion still have to happen? [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/7d4GTGvEr), `X*` and `Y*` definitely are definitely differently valued pointers. Does this not qualify as a conversion?

Comment: @chrysante The rules for implicit conversion sequences are only used for overload resolution. The actual call follows the usual member function call rules, e.g. https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#6.sentence-4.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this one but not sure it qualifies:

```
struct A {
    A(int a) {} 
};

void foo(A&& a) {
    
}

int main() {
    foo(1.3);
}
```

- double to int is standard
- int to A is user defined
- rvalue to lvalue is standard (temporary A to parameter a)

Comment: `A` to `const A` is not a conversion: https://eel.is/c++draft/over#best.ics.general-6.sentence-4. In fact top-level `const` in a function parameter isn't even part of the function type and can't affect overload resolution at all.

Comment: I edited my answer trying an rvalue to lvalue conversion as a second standard.

Comment: The temporary materialization conversion is not listed as a standard conversion (https://eel.is/c++draft/conv#general-1) and the reference is ignored when determining the implicit conversion sequence (except that the reference binding may make it invalid later), see https://eel.is/c++draft/over#ics.ref-2.sentence-1.